# SRX220: Cant ping between hosts in directly attached networks through SRX

Tags: juniper, srx

I have such lab: SRX220H and 2 hosts.

```
Host1 (IP-address 192.168.1.100/24) connected to SRX interface ge-0/0/1 (interface address 192.168.1.1/24);   
Host2 (IP-address 10.10.1.100/24) connected to SRX interface ge-0/0/2 (interface address 10.10.1.1/24);
```

So I can ping from Host1 (IP-address 192.168.1.100/24) interface ge-0/0/2 (interface address 10.10.1.1/24),
BUT CAN'T ping from Host1 (IP-address 192.168.1.100/24) Host2 (IP-address 10.10.1.100/24)

Also, I can ping from Host2 (IP-address 10.10.1.100/24) interface ge-0/0/1 (interface address 192.168.1.1/24); 
BUT CAN'T ping from Host2 (IP-address 10.10.1.100/24) Host1 (IP-address 192.168.1.100/24).

```
root# run show configuration
## Last commit: 2013-04-18 17:10:04 GMT+5 by root
version 11.2R4.3;

system {
    time-zone GMT+5;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$aOk8oeeK$ECtJa89jmEN22kQEHi9z./"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }

    name-server {
        208.67.222.222;
        208.67.220.220;
    }
    services {
        ssh;
        telnet;
        xnm-clear-text;
        web-management {
            http {
                interface vlan.0;
            }
            https {
                system-generated-certificate;
                interface vlan.0;
            }
        }
    }
    syslog {
        archive size 100k files 3;
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any critical;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands error;
        }
        file prb1 {
            any any;
            match 192.1.1.1;
        }
    }
    max-configurations-on-flash 5;
    max-configuration-rollbacks 5;
    license {
        autoupdate {
            url https://ae1.juniper.net/junos/key_retrieval;
        }
    }
}

interfaces {

    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.10.1.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
protocols {

    stp;
}
security {

    flow {
        traceoptions {
            file tshoot;
            flag basic-datapath;
            packet-filter ping1 {
                source-prefix 192.168.1.100/32;
                destination-prefix 10.10.1.100/24;
            }
        }
    }
    policies {
        from-zone lan to-zone lan {
            policy lan-to-lan {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                    log {
                        session-init;
                        session-close;
                    }
                    count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone lan {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
                protocols {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                ge-0/0/1.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            all;
                        }
                        protocols {
                            all;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ge-0/0/2.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result of pinging Host2 (IP-address 10.10.1.100/24) from Host1 (IP-address 192.168.1.100/24)
In my opinion it's stange things in debug in following strings:

```
Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  choose interface ge-0/0/2.0 as outgoing phy if
Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  route lookup: dest-ip 192.168.1.100 orig ifp ge-0/0/1.0 output_ifp ge-0/0/1.0 orig-zone 6 out-zone 6 vsd 0



root# run show log tshoot
Apr 18 17:22:51  clear-log[3459]: logfile cleared
Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:<192.168.1.100/54->10.10.1.100/1;1> matched filter ping1:

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:packet [60] ipid = 5479, @423fda1e

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:---- flow_process_pkt: (thd 1): flow_ctxt type 13, common flag 0x0, mbuf 0x423fd800, rtbl_idx = 0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: flow process pak fast ifl 68 in_ifp ge-0/0/1.0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  ge-0/0/1.0:192.168.1.100->10.10.1.100, icmp, (8/0)

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: find flow: table 0x4ed7f820, hash 59760(0xffff), sa 192.168.1.100, da 10.10.1.100, sp 54, dp 1, proto 1, tok 6

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  no session found, start first path. in_tunnel - 0, from_cp_flag - 0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow_first_create_session

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow_first_in_dst_nat: in <ge-0/0/1.0>, out <N/A> dst_adr 10.10.1.100, sp 54, dp 1

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  chose interface ge-0/0/1.0 as incoming nat if.

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:flow_first_rule_dst_xlate: DST no-xlate: 0.0.0.0(0) to 10.10.1.100(1)

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:flow_first_routing: vr_id 0, call flow_route_lookup(): src_ip 192.168.1.100, x_dst_ip 10.10.1.100, in ifp ge-0/0/1.0, out ifp N/A sp 54, dp 1, ip_proto 1, tos 0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:Doing DESTINATION addr route-lookup

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  routed (x_dst_ip 10.10.1.100) from lan (ge-0/0/1.0 in 0) to ge-0/0/2.0, Next-hop: 10.10.1.100

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  policy search from zone lan-> zone lan (0x0,0x360001,0x1)

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  app 0, timeout 60s, curr ageout 60s

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:flow_first_src_xlate:  nat_src_xlated: False, nat_src_xlate_failed: False

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:flow_first_src_xlate: src nat returns status: 0, rule/pool id: 0/0, pst_nat: False.

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  dip id = 0/0, 192.168.1.100/54->192.168.1.100/54 protocol 0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  choose interface ge-0/0/2.0 as outgoing phy if

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:is_loop_pak: No loop: on ifp: ge-0/0/2.0, addr: 10.10.1.100, rtt_idx:0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:jsf sess interest check. regd plugins 19

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: Allocating plugin info block for 19 plugin(s) from OL

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  2, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  3, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  5, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  6, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  7, svc_req 0x2. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id  8, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 11, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:+++++++++++jsf_test_plugin_data_evh: 3

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 12, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 13, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 14, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 17, svc_req 0x0. rc 2

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:-jsf int check: plugin id 18, svc_req 0x0. rc 4

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: No JSF plugins enabled for session

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: Releasing plugin info block for 19 plugin(s) to OL

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:flow_first_service_lookup(): natp(0x4b8f66b8): app_id, 0(0).

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  service lookup identified service 0.

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow_first_final_check: in <ge-0/0/1.0>, out <ge-0/0/2.0>

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:construct v4 vector for nsp2

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  existing vector list 200-456272a0.

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  Session (id:6216) created for first pak 200

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow_first_install_session======> 0x4b8f66b8

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: nsp 0x4b8f66b8, nsp2 0x4b8f6738

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  make_nsp_ready_no_resolve()

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  route lookup: dest-ip 192.168.1.100 orig ifp ge-0/0/1.0 output_ifp ge-0/0/1.0 orig-zone 6 out-zone 6 vsd 0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  route to 192.168.1.100

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:no need update ha

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:Installing c2s NP session wing

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:Installing s2c NP session wing

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow got session.

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:  flow session id 6216

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: vector bits 0x200 vector 0x456272a0

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT:mbuf 0x423fd800, exit nh 0x80010

Apr 18 17:22:59 17:22:58.1648803:CID-0:RT: ----- flow_process_pkt rc 0x0 (fp rc 0)
```

SOME USEFUL TESTS

```
root# run ping 10.10.1.100 source 10.10.1.1
PING 10.10.1.100 (10.10.1.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.1.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=3.797 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.1.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.999 ms
^C
--- 10.10.1.100 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.999/2.898/3.797/0.899 ms
```

Test2

```
root# run ping 10.10.1.100 source 192.168.1.1
PING 10.10.1.100 (10.10.1.100): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.10.1.100 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Test3

```
root# run ping 192.168.1.100 source 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=15.049 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.193 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.100 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.193/8.621/15.049/6.428 ms
```

Test4

```
root# run ping 192.168.1.100 source 10.10.1.1
PING 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.1.100 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Test5

```
root# run ping 10.10.1.1 source 192.168.1.1
PING 10.10.1.1 (10.10.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.809 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.685 ms
^C
--- 10.10.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.685/0.747/0.809/0.062 ms
```

Test6

```
root# run show route

inet.0: 4 destinations, 4 routes (4 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

10.10.1.0/24       *[Direct/0] 00:13:13
                    > via ge-0/0/2.0
10.10.1.1/32       *[Local/0] 00:52:39
                      Local via ge-0/0/2.0
192.168.1.0/24     *[Direct/0] 00:47:46
                    > via ge-0/0/1.0
192.168.1.1/32     *[Local/0] 00:52:39
                      Local via ge-0/0/1.0
```

Can you send me example of config for SRX220 with some directly attached networks in one security zone with ping allowed between hosts in these networks

Answer (score 2):

Put both interfaces in the same zone:

```
set security zones security-zone trust interface ge-0/0/2.0
set security zones security-zone trust interface ge-0/0/3.0
```

Create a policy to permit intra-zone traffic.

```
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy trust-to-trust match source-address any destination address any application any
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy trust-to-trust then permit
```

That's all that's needed, you can optionally log and count the traffic as well. This is all easily available in the documentation. My syntax may not be perfect there as I don't have a Junos device in front of me to clean up that code.